# indexOfObject does not match correctly

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, cocoa-touch, string

I've been stuck with this problem from a couple of days and I can't get myself out of it.
I've searched all over the net, but I couldn't find anything useful to solve my issue.

this is the scenario.

I've got an array of strings containing a bunch of ids fetched from a coredata sqlite db and 
I'd like to know the index of a certain element into this array.

My first solution would have been as easy as using indexOfObject

```
-(NSInteger) getPageId:(NSString *)symbol_id {
    NSInteger refId = [myIds indexOfObject:symbol_id];
    // .. stuff ..
    return refId;
}
```

now, I don't know why, but the returning value of the function is always NSNotFound.
If I print out the values via NSLog

```
NSLog(@"%@\n%@", myIds, symbol_id);
```

I can clearly see that the value I'm searching for figures out into the elements of the array.

I've even tried a dumbest solution, like probing the match via isEqual function into a for loop:

```
int idx = 0;
for(NSString *tok in myIds) {
   if([tok isEqual:synmbol_id])
   {
     NSLog(@"yay, a match was encountered!!");
     return idx;
   }
   idx++;
}
```

but the execution never gets into the NSLog.

I dunno where to knock my head.

hope that some of you already figured this out and could explain this to me.

thx in advance

k

Comment: May I suggest an encoding problem ? try to compare the length of your strings to confirm.

Comment: How are you storing the items in the myIds array? (You might want to update your question with the relevant code.)

Comment: ok I guess I've found it. the problem was into the core data part, cose all the data had a \t before. Shame on you, core-data!  Thx you so much guys, you're awsum!

Comment: if you have found the solution then please share that. That may help other people.

Comment: Do not name methods `get*` unless you are following Cocoa/UIKit patterns (which this does not).  It should be something like `pageIDForSymbol:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing all the elements on the array like this:

```
for(NSString *tok in myIds) {
   NSLog(@"On the array [%@]", tok);
}
```

Maybe there is a TAB `\t`, an ENTER `\n` or something weird in your `NSString` preventing `isEqual` message to run as expected. Usually these characters are hard to find on a regular debugger. That's why I'am suggesting to enclose the string in `[]`.

Comment: yay, the problem was in the array consolidation part, that caused me to have every element starting with a \t. core data was the blame. so by stripping the string a the array initing I solved the problem, now it works like a charm.